# How should my table look like (code) in my PhpMyAdmin, for this 'Like' button to work

Tags: php, sql

I wanna create a table in my PhpMyAdmin to be able to use this code ...

```
if($_POST['like']) 
{   
echo "BlahBlahBlah.";
$sql = "UPDATE table set `likes` = `likes`+1 where `product_id` = '1'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
}

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
<input type = "submit" name="like" value = 'like'"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes you want that. But what did you do and why didn't it work? Is it because of reserved words in mysql that collide with the name of your table probably?

Comment: this is not a question about phpMyAdmin ( an admin tool), but database design... as hakre said, be carefull with your table / column names, some words are reserved for internal use in (my)sql. I asume "`table`" is just a placeholder for the actual table name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

Table name: "table"
fields:

1. "product_id" int primary_key auto_increment
2. "likes"      int default:0

auto increment is not required but is advisable. Also you might want some additional fields in there with extra info.

Comment: Ok, I did one tabel name: table and I added two fields like you wrote, but nothing happens ...

Comment: If the database record does not exist already, you can't update it. You need some form of autocomplete: `if ($result===false)` this means the update failed and you should insert the record instead with `$sql="INSERT INTO table(product_id, likes) VALUES ($product_id,1)"

Comment: @LoveYourApp have you connected to the database before executing the query? If not, use mysql_connect to connect and mysql_select_db to select a database:   
`$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123"); mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);`

Comment: $Flame Thanks, for the help ... I did the 'product_id wrong', but Its working now ...

Answer (score 0):

Your table will contain two fields as below

```
like int()

product_id primary key
```

Comment: Thanks for that tips. Im gonna make two fields like you say, but what should the name of my tabel be?

Comment: `table` will be the name of table

Comment: Ok, I made a tabel with tabel name:tabel, and the two fields like you wrote, but nothing happens ... Can you help me get my code(tabels) to work correct?

Comment: Ok, can you help me with that code(how to post my created tabel)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what you're liking. Which video, message, item or other thing. I always do something like this (taking videos as example):

[image: table relation for like]

Now we're able to know which video has how many likes. In your save script you have to know the `video_id` to be able to update the likes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand that, but with my tabels that I already have how do I know my id?